# Implementing openStreetMap for Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, openstreetmap

I'm trying to implement openStreetMap for Android Compose following the instructions at https://utsmannn.github.io/osm-android-compose/. But the OpenStreetMap composite function is marked as an unresolved link.

Problem solved: In gradle implementation library on site has wrong name:

```
tech.utsmankece:osm-androd-compose:${latest_version}.
```

Сorrect library name must be:

```
tech.utsmankece:osm-android-compose:${latest_version}.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install dependencies**

```
// MapLibre SDK
implementation("org.maplibre.gl:android-sdk:9.6.0")
implementation("org.maplibre.gl:android-sdk-turf:5.9.0")
// MapLibre plugins
implementation ("org.maplibre.gl:android-plugin-localization-v9:1.0.0")
implementation ("org.maplibre.gl:android-plugin-annotation-v9:1.0.0")
implementation ("org.maplibre.gl:android-plugin-markerview-v9:1.0.0")
```

**Create MapCompose.kt file**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleEventObserver
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMapOptions
import com.telecom.menzil.R

@Composable
fun rememberMapViewLifecycle(): MapView {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mapboxMapOptions = MapboxMapOptions()

// Enable texture mode
    mapboxMapOptions.textureMode(true)
    val mapView = remember {
        Mapbox.getInstance(context)
        MapView(context).apply {
            id = R.id.map
            onCreate(Bundle())
        }
    }

    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle

    DisposableEffect(key1 = lifecycle, key2 = mapView){
        val lifecycleObserver = getMapLifecycleObserver(mapView)
        lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        }
    }

    return mapView
}

private fun getMapLifecycleObserver(mapView: MapView): LifecycleEventObserver =
    LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> mapView.onCreate(Bundle())
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> mapView.onStart()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> mapView.onResume()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> mapView.onPause()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> mapView.onDestroy()
            else -> throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
  val map = rememberMapViewLifecycle()
AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .zIndex(0f),
            factory = {
                map.apply {
                    getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->
                        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromUri("asset://local_style_file.json")) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            update = {

            }
                )
```

**Add local_style_file.json file to the assets folder like below, openstreatmap tile server url also here**

[Style json](https://github.com/teamapps-org/maplibre-gl-styles/blob/main/osm-liberty/style-local.json)

Comment: Openstreatmap XYZ tile url: https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png